# How to create deb packages for fonts

Tags: apt, package-management, fonts, packaging

How do I create a package of fonts? I am not going to be uploading them to the Archive as they are for my own use.

Can anyone point me to a tutorial or a document on creating font packages?

I have managed to create a wallpaper package using dpkg-deb but I have a feeling that I need to do something more as I would need to run fc-cache as well.

I do not have the source files to these fonts as I have just downloaded them from the web so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When installing a font package, you don't need to run `fc-cache` manually. In the past, this used to be done by a postinst script included in each font package, but now `fontconfig` installs a dpkg trigger that automatically regenerates the font cache whenever a new file is placed in `/usr/share/fonts` by any package.

So a Debian package for a font file, is extremely simple. You just need a `debian/install` file that places the font in the correct directory, like:

```
*.ttf usr/share/fonts/truetype/myfont
```

See [the Debian font team's packaging policy wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/Fonts/PackagingPolicy) for more information.