# How to download and install the Roboto Mono font?

Tags: fonts

How can I download and install the Roboto **Mono** font on Ubuntu?

This is the font I am referring to:

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Mono

It is a monospaced version of the Roboto fonts.

The above page does not have a download link, and the `fonts-roboto` package only contains the proportional Roboto fonts, so I cannot use [this duplicate here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts)...

Comment: That's two questions: How to use the Google Fonts website (which seems off-topic here and [easy enough to learn from Google](https://developers.google.com/fonts/faq#can_i_download_the_fonts_on_google_fonts_to_my_own_computer)), and [How to Install Fonts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3697/how-do-i-install-fonts) (which is already answered).

Comment: @user535733, you answered my question. (I thought there might be a ppa or deb package I could use, but I can download and install manually).

Comment: If you want to install **Roboto** and not Roboto *Mono*, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171447/how-do-i-install-the-roboto-font)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to this [link](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Mono) and click on **SELECT THIS FONT**. Then a dialog box appears from bottom of the page. Click on that dialog box and then hover on **Download** icon in the top-right corner of that dialog box. It will open a small dialog box in which you get the following options(links) :-

**Use SkyFonts** and **Download**

[image]

Click on **Download** option. It downloads a file named **Roboto_Mono.zip**. Go to your *Downloads* folder and extract that zip file. It will create a folder named *Roboto_Mono*. Open this folder. Inside it, you will find different **.ttf** files.

[image]

Click on each of them(one-by-one) to open it in Font Viewer and then click on **Install** button in the top-right corner.

Following this procedure, you will have Roboto Mono installed on your Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 10):

Download the .ttf files from the [official Roboto Mono git repository](https://github.com/googlefonts/RobotoMono) and put them in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/robotomono` with this command:

```
sudo wget --content-disposition -P /usr/share/fonts/truetype/robotomono https://github.com/googlefonts/RobotoMono/tree/main/fonts/ttf/RobotoMono-{Bold,BoldItalic,Italic,Light,LightItalic,Medium,MediumItalic,Regular,Thin,ThinItalic}.ttf?raw=true
```

`--content-disposition` is to accept the file name from github.com (otherwise the files would have `.ttf?raw=true` at the end, instead of just `.ttf`) and `-P` is to tell `wget` which directory to save the results (the directory and any sub-directories you need to create will be created automatically)

Comment: it's a good one - I can see the font with fc-cache , but XFCE-terminal4 doesn't want to see it ! :D

Comment: the answer is somekind beginer-friendly but I really like your answer, so fast (Y)

Comment: @Luke the real answer would be to [contribute an install script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534857/how-to-create-deb-packages-for-fonts) to Debian, so then people could just do `sudo apt install fonts-roboto-mono`

Answer (score 2):

This should do:
`apt-get install fonts-roboto`

Another command for some other fonts of interest:

`apt-get install fonts-lato fonts-open-sans fonts-roboto fonts-mononoki`

Comment: At least in Ubuntu 20.04, the fonts-roboto package doesn't contain the monospace variant, so this answer doesn't do what the OP wants.