# How do I install the Roboto font?

Tags: fonts

How do I install the regular, sans-serif version (not the monospace version) of [Google's Roboto font](https://github.com/google/roboto) on Ubuntu?

There's a [question about Roboto **Mono**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984563/how-to-download-and-install-the-roboto-mono-font?noredirect=1&lq=1) but my question is about Roboto, not the monospace version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download and install the Roboto Mono font?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984563/how-to-download-and-install-the-roboto-mono-font)

Comment: @guiverc Roboto Mono and Roboto are different fonts with diferent installation procedures. I think `fonts-roboto` doesn't come with Roboto Mono, but I haven't actually checked.

Comment: @guiverc someone complained that my answer there is technically not an answer (which is true, the question asks about Mono, and `apt install fonts-roboto` won't install Mono, I just checked) so I wanted to move my answer to its own question to be more correct.

Answer (score 21):

```
sudo apt install fonts-roboto
```

There's also `fonts-noto` which is also from Google and has way more characters